# Creating a class with a generic enum field. Enum field used to get enum's values

Tags: java, generics, enums

I need Class to which I can give different enum types and in this class I need to obtain all values of the given enum.

This is how I tried to do, but I have an issue defining the type of the enum field:

```
class MyClass{
  private Class<T> enumType; //how to say who is T?

  void <T extends Enum<T>> setEnumType(Class<T> enumType){
     this.enumType = enumType;
  }

  void doSomething(){
     for (Enum<T> literal : enumType.getEnumConstants()) {
         // do something with literal.name();
     }
  }
}
```

Update: I can't make the class generic (`MyClass<T extends Enum<T>>`). So I need other solution.

Comment: You'll have to make the class generic. Or use a wildcard. Will you really use the type variable `T` for anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I implemented the following solution that works:

```
class MyClass{
  private Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumType;

  void <T extends Enum<T>> setEnumType(Class<T> enumType){
     this.enumType = enumType;
  }

  void doSomething(){
     for (Enum<?> literal : enumType.getEnumConstants()) {
         // do something with literal.name();
     }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work (however I would suggest to pass the enum class in the constructor):

```
class MyClass<T extends Enum<T>> {
  private Class<T> enumType; 

  void setEnumType(Class<T> enumType){
     this.enumType = enumType;
  }

  void doSomething(){
     for (T literal : enumType.getEnumConstants()) {
         // do something with literal.name();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it works but I forgot to mention that this class is an existing class that do a lot of other things and I can't parametrize it with MyClass<T extends Enum<T>>

Comment: If you *know* which class you expect, you don't need generics, just use this class...

Comment: I don't know the class because it should serve for multiple enum types

Comment: If you have different enum types, how can you have one class to deal with all of them? Either the enums share some common behavior (e.g. they implement the same interface), or you need to make `MyClass` abstract, and deal with every enum type separately in a sub-class.

Comment: the enums are Enum and I don't want to have a common interface. Enum provides me mechanism to extract all values. That is enough for me.

Comment: I don't really understand: If enum is enough for you, the solution above should be fine. If you need special handling for certain enum types, you need either a common interface or specialization by inheritance from `MyEnum`. I have the strong feeling that your design is flawed, but can't pinpoint the problem without clarification.